# undefined reference to INIT_LIST_HEAD in list.h

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I want to use the function `INIT_LIST_HEAD` in `list.h` (here is my [list.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h?v=2.4.37)), but I get the error `undefined reference to INIT_LIST_HEAD`.
Here is my source code:

```
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        struct list_head* hd = NULL;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(hd);

        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It is not a function . It is defined as macro in your header.

Comment: The header is read only if either `__KERNEL__` or `_LVM_H_INCLUDE` are defined; there's a second `#if` guard just inside the usual inclusion guard. So one possibility is that you have included an empty header and `INIT_LIST_HEAD` is interpreted as regular function.(There's no error message for `struct list_head`, because it is okay to define a pointer to an incomplete type.)

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your reply. I understood now. So I am not able to use `INIT_LIST_HEAD()` in my program?

Comment: It's a Linux kernel header. Not meant to be used as is in user code. It may work if you fiddle with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#include <linux/lvm.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <linux/list.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry to bother you, but I have tried and it takes no effect :(